# setState() not showing up in the suggested widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The setState function is not showing up and typing it properly isn't helping either. I want to use it in the InkWell onTap but its just not showing up! Any help please?[Here you can see what I am trying to say!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0wqg.png)

Comment: I think you were using `setState(...)` inside `child`, instead of `onTap`.

Answer (score 1):

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
        setState(() {

        });
    },
)
```

Try like this.... 
not able to see your whole code because of suggestions.

Comment: Its back now! Working perfectly. Btw I had done the same it was just that the setState was somehow not showing up even after typing it correctly! thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this is the case

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () => {
        // arrow should not be here. 
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.favorite,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 27,
        ),
      )
```